# open android ios app from email

Tags: android, ios, email, launch

I am looking for suggestions from experts in this group.

We have a website, ios and Android apps. In the web site there is a banner available for our mobile application. So if user taps on that banners and app is installed in the mobile, then it should launch the app (ios & android). If app is not installed then we need to display a custom web page there all the details about the application is provided.

Also we are sending emails to our customers to let them know about the application. There will be hyper link in the email. From the email, when the user taps on the hyper link, and if the app is installed, then it should launch the app (ios & android) and if app is not installed then it should display a customer website.

And the custom web page we can show app store links.

Could somebody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

For iOS, you can try this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

and this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html